# Github Actions path to description is wrong

Tags: github, build, github-actions

My partners and I are trying to build our package with github actions, but we keep getting stuck here. We have never built a package before in R, and have basically been trying to figure out why the path to our description file is wrong. It should be:

/Users/runner/work/data-534-project-Sophia_Yuxian_Graham/DESCRIPTION

But is:

In read.dcf(path) :
cannot open compressed file '/Users/runner/work/data-534-project-Sophia_Yuxian_Graham/data-534-project-Sophia_Yuxian_Graham/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

[image: github actions log]

The link to our repo is below for reference.

https://github.com/Graham693/data-534-project-Sophia_Yuxian_Graham

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this path is incorrect based on the setup of our repo?

Comment: Could you include your workflow file in your question?

Comment: Also, the path to the working directory in a workflow is typically `$HOME/work/reponame/reponame`: See [here](https://github.com/jidicula/test-actions/runs/1943006964?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:4) for a minimal example, from the workflow line [here](https://github.com/jidicula/test-actions/blob/cc2cebca5233a48fef6eeb1cb6591235dd2fb25c/.github/workflows/main.yml#L11).

Comment: As @jidicula said, the path is fine, it is normal that you see the reponame twice. Did you make sure that the file exists? You can run a step with ls.

Answer (score -1):

Is it expected to have reponame two times on path ?
$HOME/work/**reponame**/**reponame**:

Comment: I think this should be a comemnt. Or at least please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."